# How do I do multiple CASE WHEN, using LEAD() to look at an entire row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data that I need to manually adjust a column (inserting 0) for the row trailing a specific row, based on a record in one specific column. For example:

My desired output:

| TYPE | ObjectID | DATE | AMT1 | AMT2 | AMT3 | AMT4 | TOTAL AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1234 | 3/1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 1234 | 3/2 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| B | 1234 | 3/3 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 |

Looking at the TYPE column, **only when the type of the current row is 'A',** I want whatever is in the AMT2 column **below** it to be populated in the TOTAL AMT column for that row. If the amount in the AMT2 column is 0, then I need the amount in column AMT4. Otherwise, I want the TOTAL AMT column to be a total of AMT1 and AMT3. Then on top of all of that, I need the TOTAL AMT column to have 0 hardcoded into it for the row **below** TYPE 'A' (instead of summing AMT1 and AMT3).

I used the LEAD() function to get the first part of my problem handled (retrieving the value from AMT2 for the TOTAL AMT column), but I'm struggling with how to get the rest in another CASE WHEN (if that's even the right approach) that will allow me to get AMT4 and hardcode the 0 in for the specific row needed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I'm using for retrieving the AMT2 from the below row:

```sql
CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN LEAD(AMT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID ORDER BY DATE ASC)      
     ELSE (AMT1 + AMT3)
END AS TOTAL AMT
```

Comment: why not try using multiple case statements in your partitioning to handle the rules

Comment: Please add script for create table, add sample datas and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you just need a nested case expression:

```
case when 
  type = 'A' then 
    lead(AMT2) over (partition by ObjectID order by DATE)      
else 
  case when lag(type) over (partition by ObjectID order by DATE)='A' then 
    0 
  else
    AMT1 + AMT3 
  end
end as TOTALAMT;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3932c30ed46de86d6afd92301e3917e8)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: If I need to add another condition to the case expression, how do I do that? Specifically, assuming there is now a new column (AMT4), I need to use the amount in that column whenever lead(AMT2) over (partition by ObjectID order by DATE)=0 after type 'A'. Should I post as a new question?

Comment: I unmarked this as the answer for now, but I will remark it once my recent edit to the question has been addressed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using lead and case ([result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3757755d114f9b05141f2ccbef84e87a))

```
select *,case type when 'A' then lead(amt2,1) over (partition by objectid order by date) else amt1+amt3 end as total
from t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is the code I already have. I'm looking for a way to use this same code, but also provide a hardcoded amount (0) for the row below TYPE 'A'. In this case, with the results you provided, I would want to see '0' in the TOTAL AMT column for TYPE 'B'.

Comment: Is the `TOTAL AMT` for Type 'B' always `0` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, only in this case because it comes after Type 'A'.

Comment: When the previous type is A you want `0` for `TOTAL AMT` ?

Comment: That is correct.